# How to wait for multiple jobs in Android ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Given the following components

```
data class Account(val name: String)

data class GetAccountRequest(val name: String)

@Dao
interface AccountDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY name ASC")
    fun all(): LiveData<List<Account>>
}

interface AccountOperations {
    @GET("/foo/account")
    suspend fun getAccount(@Body request: GetAccountRequest): Account
}

class AccountRepository(private val dao: AccountDao, private val api: AccountOperations) {
    val accounts: LiveData<List<Account>> = dao.all()

    suspend fun refresh(name: String) {
        val account = api.getAccount(GetAccountRequest(name))
        dao.insert(account)
    }
}
```

I am working on an Android application that is using these components (powered by Room for the database and Retrofit for API access).

In my ViewModel I maintain a RecyclerView that lists all accounts. I enable users to refresh that list manually. The respective (part of the) ViewModel looks like this:

```
fun refresh() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.accounts.value?.forEach {
            launch { repository.refresh(it.name) }
        }
    }
    Timber.i("Done refreshing!")
}
```

I do want the refresh to update all accounts in parallel, this is why I am using `launch`. I have also decided to do this in the ViewModel, rather than in the repository, since that would have required to launch a new coroutine in the repository. Which per [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-iii-real-work-2ba8a2ec2f45) is discouraged since repositories don't have a natural lifecycle.

The above function, `refresh`, is invoked from the UI and shows a refresh-indicator while the RecyclerView is updated. So I want to stop this indicator once all accounts have been updated.

My code as shown above doesn't do this, since it will launch all the updates and then print the log statement before all updates have been finished. As a result the refresh-indicator disappears although there are still updates.

So my question (finally) is: how can I refactor the code so that it runs all updates in parallel, but makes sure `refresh` doesn't return before all of them have finished?

**EDIT #1**

Going back to what I want to achieve: showing the refresh-indicator while the view is updating, I came up with the following (changed the `refresh` function in the ViewModel):

```
fun refresh() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                coroutineScope {
                    _refreshing.value = true
                    repository.accounts.value?.map { account ->
                        async {
                            repository.refresh(account.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (cause: CancellationException) {
                throw cause
            } catch (cause: Exception) {
                Timber.e(cause)
            } finally {
                _refreshing.value = false
            }
        }
    }
```

The ViewModel exposes a LiveData for when it is refreshing and the fragment can observe it to show or hide the spinner. This seems to do the trick. However, it still doesn't feel right and I appreciate any improved solutions.

Comment: `async` is for parallelism, not structured concurrency

Answer (score 0):

In order to `await` for all of your parallel `refresh()` operations, simply use `awaitAll()`:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
            _refreshing.value = true

            repository.accounts.value?.map { account ->
                async {
                    repository.refresh(account.name)
                }
            }.awaitAll()

            _refreshing.value = false
        }
```

Furthermore, It's not advised to wrap coroutines with `try/catch`. 
You can read more on this [here](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-coroutines-patterns-anti-patterns-f9d12984c68e).

Comment: Thanks. I have read through the article but couldn't find the section where it says that wrapping coroutines with `try/catch` is discouraged. Can you elaborate on that one? Also, how else would you handle exceptions in this scenario?

I am using `coroutineScope` in my example and I think that I don't need to invoke `awaitAll()`, since that seems to happen automatically.

Comment: No problem @aix, :) the first section of that article, after the intro suggests that wrapping coroutines with `try/catch` comes with several consequences, which in your case, you correctly handled it by throwing the `CancellationException` after catching it (provided that you have a `SupervisorJob` for your scope), then you are safe here. 
Answering your second question, for catching all the exceptions at the root level, I'll add `CoroutineExceptionHandler` to my root `CoroutineContext`.